# ios Photo never finish upload after switching app

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, ios

At the bottom of 'Photos' in my photo app, there is some status text that says

```
35555 Photos, 2152 videos, 1 item
Uploading 244 Photos (12.1MB of 389.3MB)
```

[image]

The upload starts when the Photo is running in the foreground.

However if I switched to another app and back, the uploading line will become:

```
Uploading 244 Photos (0MB of 389.3MB)
```

and slowing climbing back to the previous high watermark.

I think these 244 photos are waiting for upload for at least a week now (since I last take note of the text)

How can I make the Photo app to continue even though it is running in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to run the photo in the foreground, connect the iphone to power and let it run for the whole night. The message is finally gone in the morning.

However now the message has become "Uploading 38,160 items". It is attempting to re-upload everything from my iphone. My older photo are not accessible now (a exclamation icon is shown on the lower right corner on all my older photo)

[image]

There must be a more serious problem with icloud.

Answer (score -2):

You mean Google Photos, right?

If so, I would recommend to restart your iPhone, click on the Photo app and let it upload remain pictures & video.